# Does FFMPEG support AES128 Sample encryption required for Apple Fairplay DRM?

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, fairplay

I need to encrypt an MPEG2 Transport stream with Sample AES encryption compatible with Fairplay DRM. Does FFMPEG support Sample AES encryption (just like how it supports Common Encryption for Widevine and Playready DRMs) ?

Comment: No. Look into https://www.bento4.com/

Comment: Thanks. Per my knowledge and study, bento4 is a sort of MP4 focused. Its support for Sample encryption is through its tool "mp4hls" which takes mp4 file as input and re-packages it into HLS with optional Sample Encryption. Suppose I have my input in HLS (and MPEG2-TS) format itself and I just need this stream to be encrypted, BentO4 doesn't seem to be a straight-forward choice. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As per the docs for mp42hls, what you could do is remux your TS to MP4 and then use mp42hls to generate a single segment TS with encryption.

Comment: Thanks again.., but this double processing may hit the performance if I'm having to do any realtime video processing.. I wonder why ffmpeg doesn't yet support native Sample Encryption